# Java XML transformer error on attribute : Namespace for prefix 'req' has not been declared

Tags: java, xml

My XML in `test.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<record>
    <req1:name>john</req1:name>
    <age req:valid="f">57</age>
</record>
```

My Java code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document  = documentBuilder.parse(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.xml"));
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document),result);
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

When running the `transformer.transform` will throw an exception

> Namespace for prefix 'req' has not been declared

If I remove the req: prefix from the attribute it's working. There is no exception for the req1 prefix. The exception only appears for attributes.

Is there a way disable that kind of validation ?

I tried with

```
documentBuilderFactory.setValidating(false);
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
```

but it changes nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Transformer how to ignore namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918197/java-transformer-how-to-ignore-namespaces)

Answer (score -1):

namespace needs to be declared

try

```
<record xmlns:req="http://your-ns-url">
<!-- ... -->
</record>
```

Edit:

If you just want to get rid of the exception add the namspace to the doc root before transforming to string

```
Element documentElement = document.getDocumentElement();
// Add name space to root element as attribute
documentElement.setAttribute("xmlns:req", "http://you_name_space");
```

Comment: Ok I know.  In my real application I only have a DOM document.  Probably there is somewhere an  attribute with req prefix.  When I try to transform it into string  have the exception.  So I want to display the xml to check where is that attribute.